# Xamarin iOS load content in UIWebView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uiwebview, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to make a custom web page and put it in a webview in Xamarin using C#
What I have is a UIViewController containing a UIWebView.
In my project I have a folder like this:

- Project

  - Content

    - index.html
    - js
    - css

But when I try to load the index.html file into the webview nothing happens. 
I tried just loading an external webpage and it works fine.

this is my code for loading the content in the ViewDidLoad method of the UIViewController:

```
string fileName = "Content/index.html";
string localHtmlUrl = Path.Combine(NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, fileName);
MyWebView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(localHtmlUrl, false)));
MyWebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
```

I think it has something to do with the page not finishing it's loading, but I can't figure out how to do this properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derp, always make sure to set the 'Build Action' on your file to BundleResource on each file to include them in the build by right clicking on them...